# Remove field from a map of properties

Tags: groovy

Hi everyone I am working with a properties map in Groovy, I had transformed the object to a map using the `.properties` method. I have to remove the class property from this map as in the next image:

[image]

I am using the `.remove` method to achieve this:

```
def map = podCast.properties.remove("class")
```

But after apply the remove method my map looks like this:

[image]

Without any property, I am not really sure why it is happening, maybe it is because of obtain the map with the `.properties` method?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) on a `Map` will modify your map and return the value for the given key so what you're doing is assigning `map` to that value rather than all the properties.

First assign your `map` variable to the object's properties instead of the result of calling `.remove("class")`, *then* remove the `class` property.

```
def map = podCast.properties
map.remove("class")
```